# How to console log something, when text1 and text2 are matched?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
type hereimport './App.css';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState()

  const People = {
    name: 'jack'
  }
  const peoples = People.map(() => ({
    nick: People.name
  })
  )

  const funct = () =>{
    if (text === peoples.nickname) {
      console.log('worked')
    } else {
      console.log('not worked')
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <input onChange={(event) => {setText(event.target.value)}}/>
      <h1>{text}</h1>
      <br />
      <button onClick={funct}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );

}

export default App;
```

I'm hoping that you can solve my question,and show my at what point am i wrong. Thank you very much. I've just tried to map the text and it still doesn't work and also i've tried to make the text as an object but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You are comparing a string to an array. That is not going to work. BUT before that you are trying to map an Object? Is your `People` object supposed to be an array of objects??

Comment: What is `People.map` supposed to do?

Comment: This seems to be a series of ongoing errors.  Take it one step at a time in your code.  What value do you expect `peoples` to have and why?  When you debug, does it have that value?  What value do you expect `peoples.nickname` to have and why?  When you debug, does it have that value?  Overall it looks like you have no idea what data you're putting in your variables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing an array with a string and because of this, it's not working.

you need to update your `funct` to something like this:

```
  const funct = () =>{
    peoples.forEach((p) => {
     if (p.nickname === text) {
       console.log('worked')
     } else {
       console.log('not worked')
     }
    })
  }
```

Comment: for now i cant i need to have 15 reputation, etc.

Comment: `peoples` is not a array and `p.nickname` does not exist

Answer (score 0):

When trying to create a **array** of people you try to use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on a **object**. This is not possible since you can only use `map` on a array.

To fix this you could do something like this to create a array with a new object in it which contains a property `nick` with the value of `People.name`

```js
const peoples = [{ nick: People.name }];
```

Then in the if statement you're checking for `peoples.nickname` while we just created a object with a property called `nick`.

```js
if (text === peoples.nick) {
  ...
}
```

Now this in not yet going to work. Like mentioned in the comments you're comparing a ***string*** with a ***array***. To solve this you can use some kind of loop

```js
const funct = () => {
  for (const people of peoples) {
    if (text === people.nick) {
      console.log("worked");
    } else {
      console.log("did not work");
    }
  }
};
```

Or we can use the [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) function to check if **all** the people in the array have match the `text` value

```js
const funct = () => {
  const allPeoplesValidNick = peoples.every((people) => people.nick === text);

  if (allPeoplesValidNick) {
    console.log("worked");
  } else {
    console.log("not worked");
  }
};
```